# Laravel - How to catch "HttpExceptions", because of POST request when CSFR is wrong?

Tags: laravel

So the User logs out on one tab and on the other tab he is "visually" still logged in.

Now, for example, the user sends a Chat message via POST route, but the server responds with:

```
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 419 
exception: "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException"
```

The reason is that the CSFR Value is false, because the User is logged out.

My wish is to have the same response like in GET Request Methods.

There I get:

```
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 401 
message: "Unauthenticated."
```

Because the User is not authenticated anymore. (Middleware is set to 'auth')

Why do I need this?

I want to catch failures with axios and check if the user is unauthenticated. If so the page is reloaded.

But right now I don't know if the user is unauthenticated or if he tries to exploit my page, but has a wrong csrf token.

Comment: Does the `post` route have the `auth` middleware attached to it? It would be useful to post your routes.

Comment: @GeorgeHanson No but it has the auth middleware in the construct of the controller. I checked if there is a difference, but there is none. `Route::post('/find/search', 'FindController@search')->name('find.offer')->middleware('auth');` gives the same error

Comment: Why not reload for all CSRF errors?

Comment: @Paras I'm not sure what you mean? window.reload?

Comment: Yes, you mentioned `I want to catch failures with axios and check if the user is unauthenticated. If so the page is reloaded.`. So, if you do catch a CSRF failure on the frontend, why not reload for all situations, unauthenticated or not?

Comment: @Paras Yes you are right, I think I'm going to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Current solution in Handler.php

```
 if ($exception instanceof TokenMismatchException){
     return $request->expectsJson()
            ? response()->json(['message' => 'Invalid CSRF.'], 400)
            : abort(400);
 }
```